# How does Completely Fair Scheduling handle new Processes

Tags: linux, scheduling

I'm currently trying to understand Completely Fair Scheduling (CFS) and stumbled across something I can't understand.
Let's make an example:

- I have a process running in the background (for example tracking something). It has a priority of 0.
- After 1 hour I start a second process with the same priority.

My question is how does the first process get the chance of executing after the initialization of the secnod? Assuming that the first mentioned process doesn't have `min_vruntime` at the time. I think that in this case the `vruntime` of the second process is always lower than the `vruntime` of the first. Since both have the same priority I think that process two always gets sorted in front of the first process in the RB-Tree.

It clearly can't work that way, or does it? So what am I missing?